# Struts Action Tag working incorrectly

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a jsp page `DeclarationActivation.jsp` which is opened with the struts action tag listed below defined in struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/DeclarationDaysInput"
 type="DeclarationActivationAction"
 name="ReimbursementDeclarationDaysActionForm" input="/Error.jsp" validate="false"
 scope="request" parameter="load">
    <forward name="success" path="/CompanyAdmin/DeclarationActivation.jsp"/>
<forward name="failure" path="/Error.jsp"/>
</action>
```

In this jsp page i have a form with the action parameter as `DeclarationDaysSubmit.do`

This action parameter is also defined in `struts-config.xml`

```
<action path="/DeclarationDaysSubmit"
type="DeclarationActivationAction"
name="ReimbursementDeclarationDaysActionForm" validate="true" input="/DeclarationDaysInput.do" scope="request" parameter="submit">
<forward name="success" path="/DeclarationDaysInput.do"/>
<forward name="failure" path="/Error.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Both refer to the same class, however they have different parameter values specified in the action tags, in the first, the value of parameter is `load`, in the second, the value of parameter is `submit`.

However, when I click submit in the form in the jsp page, the second action tag is not accessed by the code, but only the first one is being accessed.